# list of lists = TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set, typeerror

I have a code that goes like that:

```
lst = [['Descendant Without A Conscience', 'good', 'happy'], ['Wolf Of The Solstice', '30000', 'sad'], ['Women Of Hope', '-4000', 'neutral'], ['Pirates Of Perfection', '65467', 'neutral'], ['Warriors And Soldiers', '-5435', 'sad'], ['Butchers And Soldiers', '76542', 'sad'], ['World Of The Mountain', '6536543', 'sad'], ['Ruination Of Dusk', '-2000', 'happy'], ['Destroying The Stars', '5435', 'happy'], ['Blinded In My Enemies', '765745.5', 'happy'], ['Descendant Without A Conscience', 'good', 'happy']]

check_lst = list(set(lst))

for movie in lst:

   if len(movie) > 3:

       raise ValueError('Invalid input.')


   elif movie[2] != movie[2].lower():

       raise ValueError('Invalid input.')

   elif len(lst) != len(check_lst):
       raise ValueError('Invalid input.')
```

for some reason my check_lst is not working and I get a TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. I'm trying to remove duplicates from my list and make my check_lst without duplicates.
what am I missing?

Comment: `set(lst)` is most likely your problem. The keys of a set cannot be lists, and since `lst` is a list of lists, this is indeed the case.

Comment: Easy way to provoke this error: `set([[]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that lists can't be keys in a set - as they are mutable. You can fix this by converting each list to a tuple, and using the tuples as the keys of the sets. The rest of the code you have posted will work as expected with the below solution.

```
lst = [['Descendant Without A Conscience', 'good', 'happy'], ['Wolf Of The Solstice', '30000', 'sad'], ['Women Of Hope', '-4000', 'neutral'], ['Pirates Of Perfection', '65467', 'neutral'], ['Warriors And Soldiers', '-5435', 'sad'], ['Butchers And Soldiers', '76542', 'sad'], ['World Of The Mountain', '6536543', 'sad'], ['Ruination Of Dusk', '-2000', 'happy'], ['Destroying The Stars', '5435', 'happy'], ['Blinded In My Enemies', '765745.5', 'happy'], ['Descendant Without A Conscience', 'good', 'happy']]

check_lst = list(set(tuple(x) for x in lst))
```

Comment: We don't even need the final conversion to a list for the rest of the code because the list is only used to determine the length. We can get the length with `len{tuple(entry) for entry in lst}`.

Comment: Agreed - I kept it as a list because I'm not sure if the rest of the OP's code requires it - and keeping variables named the same, it makes sense that `check_lst` should be a list.